# How to remove untracked files from command prompt?

Tags: git

I have some untracked files in my command prompt and I am curious is it good or bad and how can I remove them if it is better?

Comment: In general, I'd avoid having untracked files intentionally lying around because it's too easy to accidentally add and commit them. Either add them, or explicitly `.gitignore` them.

Comment: Do you want to track them or not? Do you want to keep them or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want them to not show up but you don't want to commit them, you need to use a .gitignore file. It's definitely bad to have files appearing as untracked if you don't intend to commit them, because it's very easy to accidentally add them.